# facebook likes count of images to my website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook gallery with images (User Album). I want to show the likes counts of every image on my (wordpress) website. For example, in a wp post content: " My first image is liked ***400*** times, while my second image is liked ***560*** times."

Is this possible with facebook Graph Api? Some one can help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes

> The same permissions required to view the parent object are required to view likes on that object.

Meaning, if it´s on a Facebook Page you may just be able to use an App Token (if it´s not restricted by age or location) or an Extended Page Token that is valid forever. If it´s a User Album, you would need to authorize with user_photos and an Extended User Token is only valid for 60 days - so you would have to refresh the Token once in a while.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you for reply luschn. I use a user album. Can you please tell me how to start with this?

Comment: it´s all in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/albums

Answer (score 0):

Trough the API is fairly simple.

https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.google.com&format=json

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But for url, do i need to place the image url of facebook like https://www.facebook.com/Mypage/photos/a.622034714519640.1073741826.229810283742087/622034722852970/?type=3&theater ?